# Input and output not recognized and missing \endcsname in algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I want to write an algorithm, and I have the code segment shown below, but it provides multiple errors, such as input and output commands are not recognized and I get missing `\endcsname` error. Additionally, the line numbers are not inserted, any idea how to fix all the errors and also insert the line numbers?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\Input{A vector \textbf{a}}
\Output{Bit reversed vector}
    \Function{NTT}{$\textbf{a}$}
        \State $m \gets 1$
        \State $k \gets n / 2$
        \While{$m < n$}
            \For {$i = 0$ \To $m - 1$}
                \State $jFirst \gets 2 \cdot i \cdot k$
                \State $jLast \gets jFirst + k - 1$
                \State $S \gets \psi_{rev}[m + i]$
                \For {$j = jFirst$ \To $jLast$}
                    \State $l \gets j + k$
                    \State $t \gets \textbf{a}[j]$
                    \State $u \gets \textbf{a}[l] \cdot S$
                    \State $\textbf{a}[j] \gets t + u \mod q$
                    \State $\textbf{a}[l] \gets t - u \mod q$
                \EndFor
            \EndFor
            \State $m \gets m \cdot 2$
            \State $k \gets n / 2$
        \EndWhile
        \State \Return $\textbf{a}$
    \EndFunction
    \caption{Cooley-Tukey (CT) Forward NTT}
    \label{CTAlgo}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's `\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}` actually. I have no idea where it is defined. Just using it as I'm writing paper, and using `xelatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `algpseudocode` does not provide `\Input` or `\Output` commands. You'll have to create them in the same way (say) `\Ensure` and `\Require` are produced.

Also, for numbering of the lines, you need to also use the `algorithmic` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\To}{\textbf{To }}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\textbf{Input:}]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\textbf{Output:}]}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Input{A vector \textbf{a}}
    \Output{Bit reversed vector}
    \Function{NTT}{$\textbf{a}$}
      \State $m \gets 1$
      \State $k \gets n / 2$
      \While{$m < n$}
        \For {$i = 0$ \To $m - 1$}
          \State $jFirst \gets 2 \cdot i \cdot k$
          \State $jLast \gets jFirst + k - 1$
          \State $S \gets \psi_{rev}[m + i]$
          \For {$j = jFirst$ \To $jLast$}
            \State $l \gets j + k$
            \State $t \gets \textbf{a}[j]$
            \State $u \gets \textbf{a}[l] \cdot S$
            \State $\textbf{a}[j] \gets t + u \mod q$
            \State $\textbf{a}[l] \gets t - u \mod q$
          \EndFor
        \EndFor
        \State $m \gets m \cdot 2$
        \State $k \gets n / 2$
      \EndWhile
      \State \Return $\textbf{a}$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Cooley-Tukey (CT) Forward NTT}
  \label{CTAlgo}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```